# Delete a file from directory magento 2

Tags: magento2, delete, file, filesystem

Is there any way to delete files from var directory, if the file name matched with a condition. I need to delete log files based upon given date. Please let me know how to achieve this in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

==> Please used below code

**NOTE: Please do not use the Object manager**

/**
 * If the external file is in the root folder
 */

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$fileName = "test.txt";
$file = $obj->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File');
$varDirectory = $obj->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
$varRootDir = $varDirectory->getAbsolutePath();
/*echo $varRootDir.$fileName;
die();*/
if ($file->isExists($varRootDir . $fileName))  {
    $file->deleteFile($varRootDir . $fileName);
     echo 'file ('.$varRootDir . $fileName.') delete Succssfully'."\n";
}
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**